# Server with scalability for real-time collaboration and editing

Tags: php, apache-2.4, web-server, node.js, backend

I am here, to ask for absolute input. I have setup a local `Apache Server` with `PHP 7.2` (currently), I am aware newer `PHP` exists. I know `PHP` and `Python`, I also know `Node.js` (*server/back-end*).

With `Node.js`, I can get most of the packages through `npm` command line. I been reading, `Node.js` vs. `PHP` and it all depends on what you are going to develop. In addition, I know that Golang programming can also be used in the cloud. Now I want to be able to utilize the full power of cloud computing capacity.

**Requirements:** *architecture* that is *scalable*, *modular*, *maintainable*, *secure*, and *reliable*. *Fault tolerance*.

Now the site must be able to handle multiple users operating in real-time, chatting, editing content in real-time. I know that `Html5` provides all the following APIs: `WebRTC`, `WebSocket`, `Local Storage`, and a number of options. However, I cannot decide if I shall go with: `PHP`, `Golang`, or just `Node.js` with `Vue.js`, skipping `React.js` and `Angular.js`.

Any tips, suggestions based on other’s experience from doing this, is fully welcome. The web servers will be running `Linux`/`Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirements you outlined, it sounds like Node.js may be the best choice for building your real-time collaboration and editing application. Node.js is well-suited for building real-time web applications that require bidirectional communication between the client and server. It has a large ecosystem of packages and tools available via npm, making it easy to build scalable and maintainable applications.

In terms of front-end frameworks, Vue.js is a good choice. It is a progressive JavaScript framework that is lightweight and easy to use. It is well-suited for building real-time applications and has a large and active community.

Comment: Hi Salim, thanks for your response. I plan on using the MySQL database, I seen that Node.js can handle this. What other arguments can you share, for not using PHP and/or Golang?